# Syntax for reading a formatted text file into an array, C

Tags: c, arrays

I have this text file, numbers.txt
It contains the following numbers, formatted as: 1 0 0 1 0 1 0. So it contains only 1s and 0s and a space divides them.
I'd like to read the numbers into the "a" array.

If somebody could help me and explain the code it would be amazing, I researched the internet but I don't understand many terms from Input/Output.
Here is the code that I try to make work but it doesn't. The tomb is the array that is declared as int with max 200 elements, i initialized as 0. Still not working.

```
FILE *fp;
fp=fopen("fajl.txt","r");
int c;
if (fp!=NULL) {
    while (feof(fp)!=0) {
        fscanf(fp,"%d ",&tomb[i]);
        ++i;
    }
    fclose(fp);
} else {
    printf("Nem tudtam megnyitani a fajlt\n");
}
```

Comment: Some kind of loop would be a good start. Then if only C had some kind of [file input and output support](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) that would be nice.

Comment: If you don't understand *any* of the existing resources on the internet, how will you understand the answer here?

Comment: I tried this, but it makes my application crash:     FILE* fajl = freopen("fajl.txt","r",stdin);
    int ch;
    while ((ch=fgetc(fajl)) != EOF) {
        tomb[i]=fgetc(fajl);
        i++;
        tomb_hossz++;
    }

Comment: may be a combination of `fread()` and `strtok()`. just a hint

Comment: Read a reference (like the one I previously linked) about `freopen`. Then read about *`fopen`* and `fscanf`.

Comment: But first of all you should re-read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). You might also want to learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I am still surprised, that people actually write code for such questions, where somebody wasn't even willing to dig a tiny bit into what is all present on the net.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, this will read 1 or 0 from input and put on array (max 100 presumed), i will contain the number of 1's or 0's.

```
int b[100], c;
int i = 0;
while ((i < 100) && (c = getchar()) != EOF) {
    if ((c == '1') || (c == '0'))
      b[i++] = c - '0';
}
```

Comment: But I'd need the 1 and 0 as values, not as characters, as I need to make comparisons.

Comment: @Maniak edited my answer to make b array as array of integers as you wished, accept?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    int a[100],i=0;
    fp=fopen("numbers.txt","r");
    while(i<100 && fscanf(fp,"%d",&a[i])!=EOF)
    {
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might want to add a check so you're not going beyond the bounds of the array.

Comment: We often see unformatted code in begginners questions. But in answers? please!

Comment: Well, the values are still not inserted into my "a" array. I tried with fscanf and scanf but didn't worked.

Comment: It works with printf, but it wouldn't read it into my array with scanf

Comment: I forgot to add something that influenced the rest of my application, but the problem is that now at the end of my array there are 2 big number -6710... and 445...

Comment: that is not a problem.as those numbers are also int type so those can be inserted into the array.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that those numbers are not included in my file. I only have inserted 1s and 0s into my file.

Comment: @Maniak Local variables, like the array `a` in the code in the answer, are not initialized, their values are *indeterminate*. Using this uninitialized data in any way, except initializing it, results in [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). After the loop is over, you know how many entries you read, don't access the array outside that range (`0` to `i - 1` in the example code).

Comment: Well, I did count how many entries I added, as the rest of my program's loops are limited to the count number, but it still adds me garbage numbers.

Comment: That's not very helpful, I do appreciate you trying to help, but that's not helpful at all. I am a beginner in C and I find the input/output from file quite difficult. So, if you want to help do so, but not like this.